# PHP: Get Rank from MYSQL Order

Tags: php, mysql, select

I am wondering how to get the rank of a player who was wrote to my page using:

```
    $res = $con->query("SELECT * FROM hiscores ORDER BY `0` DESC LIMIT 50");
```

I have a list of my players on my page organized by their values in column 0.  How do I get what rank the player is based on the ORDER BY?

Comment: Count all rows above the player should be sufficient?

Comment: Sorry, I have deleted my answer cause I have given a wrong answer. Your query is ok, or at least looks ok, whet is the real question? I though that is the reason on getting -1

Comment: Do you really have a column named `0` ? Couldn't you come up with a more expressive name for it?

Comment: -1 for calling a column 0

Comment: Do you want to search for a particular player with a specific `rank` or want to find the `rank` of a particular player?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should `ORDER BY score DESC`

Then something like:

```
foreach ($res as $player) {
    echo "Rank #"
       . (intval(key($player)) + 1)
       . " for player "
       . $player['playerName']
       . "<br>" . PHP_EOL;
}
```

The logic is to take the element's index and increment it by one

```
$player[0] = 1
$player[1] = 2
...
```

Comment: I got ranking working so it displays what rank they are ordered by their XP.  But how I do I fetch that rank later on in the program?

Comment: ` $rank=0;
 $temp_score=0;if($temp_score!=$row['0'])
    $rank++;` $rank

Comment: Don't use `if` without brackets :-S
If you need to fetch the exact rank of someone, you should put up a cronjob running every few minutes to update a column "rank" in your table, by the help of the above script.